# Is there a way to estimate ridge regression regularisation parameter from OLS output

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regularization, ridge-regression

When performing ridge regression there is a regularisation parameter to choose. Can a good approximate value be estimated from output from standard OLS.

Intuitively these factors seem important:
- the larger the sample N the larger the regularisation needs to be
- the more unexplainable error in fitted variable the larger the regularisation needs to be
- the amount of correlation in the explanatory variables maybe an important factor

How to combine these from OLS( and other factors) to make an estimate would be useful if it was possible. Is it possible without using a solver to minimise some objective function?

Comment: *the larger the sample N the larger the regularisation needs to be* -- did you mean the opposite?

Comment: What criterion are you proposing for selecting the regularization parameter?  We need some specific target if we're to have any hope of knowing what an approximate answer might be.

Comment: @whuber the criterion am looking to minimise by using regularisation is prediction error. So if we later do cross validation of sum of squared errors this was close to a good choice.

Comment: @RichardHardy I am adding regularisation by adding additional samples to the standardised training set/explanatory variables with response variable equal to zero. So if there are a lot of samples before adding this regularisation they need to be larger or they will be drowned out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can obtain a rough estimate of the penalty parameter from standard OLS output. People in the old days used to compute

$$ \lambda = \frac{ k \hat{\sigma }^2} {||\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}||^2}, $$
where $k$ is the number of slope coefficients, $ \hat{\sigma }$ is an estimated residual scale and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} $ is the vector of estimated slopes. This formula may be found in the old papers of Hoerl and Kennard from the 70s. My guess is that modern  crossvalidation methods produce better estimates but this may be good enough for simple problems.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why this would work.  Are you perhaps assuming the betas are the *standardized* coefficients?

Comment: @JohnK thanks for this idea I will try out, I am using standardised coefficients.

Comment: @whuber sorry for the late response. This indeed works best for standardised coefficients.

Comment: I think that might be a little misleading: if it works for standardized coefficients, then in any case where the columns are not close to standardized it's likely *not* to work and can be arbitrarily bad. Thus, it's important to be clear about what $\hat\beta$ is.